# How to store an ID after each Example is run in Scenario Outline?

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Hello I am new to Specflow and coding.

I am trying to store a value in some global declared parameters(Variable). However once the 2nd example(In scenario outline) is executed, the parameter returns Null. All my parameters are returning null.

```
 Examples:
    | UserID      | Name|
    | 111001      | AS  |
    | 114028      | AK  | //2nd Example
```

After each Scenario Outline is run I need to store an ID. In total I have 4 examples in my Feature File : scenario outline.

My Feature File

```
Scenario Outline: 8. GetUserNumber
Given I enter <UserID>, <Name>, 
And I click on Create button
And I verify if<UserID>, <Name> is same as selected in previous page
And I store the UserNumber
And I click on back button
Examples:
| UserID      | Name|
| 111001      | AS |
| 114028      | AK |
| 131001      | ASF|
| 134028      | AKA|
```

My code

```
public class User
{
    string PUP1; //Global declared variable
    string PUP2; //Global declared variable
    
    public void GetUserNum()
    {
        string UserNumPath;
    
        if (UserGrade== "G" || Age== "7")
        {
            UserNumPath= driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserId")).Text;
            PUP1 = (UserNumPath);// assigning UserNumPath to PUP1
        }
        else if (UserGrade== "H" || Age== "4")
        {
            UserNumPath= driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserId")).Text;
            PUP2= (UserNumPath); // assigning UserNumPath to PUP2
        }
    }
}
```

How can I save the ID after each Scenario Outline example has been executed?

Comment: What do you want PUP1 and PUP2 to be available to? At the moment they are private fields of the `User` class, so can only be accessed by methods of the *same instance of* the `User` class in which they were set. I believe SpecFlow creates a new instance of the classes containing the test steps for each example in the scenario, in order to isolate every test case from every other test case, to allow running test cases in parallel.

Comment: This means that your first test case will set the PUP1 and PUP2 fields for one instance of the `User` class, and your second test case will be working with a second instance of the `User` class, in which the PUP1 and PUP2 fields haven't been initialised yet.

Comment: And please bear in mind that test cases should really be independent of each other, so that it doesn't matter what order they're run in - if you've got one action which is dependent on another, consider putting them both into the same scenario.

Comment: @SbridWell, I want PUP1 and PUP2 to store an ID which I will the use in another page. For example I have a page call UserDetails and another StudentCourse. In Page UserDetail when I fill in a form and click submit, an ID (PUP22OCT20210122) is generated. I need to store that ID in my global declared variable PUP1. Once I store all 4 IDs(Storing 4 IDs because I have to 4 Example in my scenario outline) I will go to StudentCourse and verify whether those records has been credited.

Comment: @SbridWell, you mean that every time the 2nd , 3rd, 4th "example" of my scenario outline is run, all global variables of the instance User (User Class ) will be set to null?

Comment: Yes, PUP1 and PUP2 aren't really "global", they exist within the scope of the `User` class, and because they're instance (as opposed to static) fields, every instance of the `User` class has its own values for those fields, which is null when the instance is first created. If you want to submit a form which stores some information in a data store and then test that another page can retrieve the information you've stored, then I'd suggest putting the form submission and the test for retrieving the information into the same scenario. I'll share some code explaining both concepts this evening.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the step definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help illustrate my answer, here's a really simple class which is the subject of my tests:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string Speak()
    {
        switch (this.Name)
        {
            case "cat":
                return "meow";

            case "dog":
                return "woof";

            case "cow":
                return "moo";

            default:
                return "I don't know";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my feature file:

```
Feature: Animal
Scenario: Animals say the right thing
Given I am a "<AnimalName>"
When I speak
Then I say "<Says>"
Examples:
| AnimalName | Says |
| dog        | woof |
| cat        | meow |
| cow        | moo  |
```

And the implementation of the test steps in that feature file:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure;
using Xunit;

[Binding]
public class AnimalSteps
{
    private readonly ISpecFlowOutputHelper outputHelper;
    private Animal animal;
    private string whatISaid;
    private static int someStaticField;

    public AnimalSteps(ISpecFlowOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        this.outputHelper = outputHelper;

        someStaticField++;
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"In constructor: someStaticField is now {someStaticField}");

        SomeStaticClass.Counter++;
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"In constructor: SomeStaticClass.Counter is now {SomeStaticClass.Counter}");
    }

    [Given(@"I am a ""(.*)""")]
    public void Given_IAmA(string animalName)
    {
        this.animal = new Animal(animalName);
    }

    [When(@"I speak")]
    public void When_ISpeak()
    {
        this.outputHelper.WriteLine($"Storing what the animal said. Previous value: '{this.whatISaid}'");
        this.whatISaid = this.animal.Speak();
    }

    [Then(@"I say ""(.*)""")]
    public void Then_ISay(string whatToSay)
    {
        Assert.Equal(whatToSay, this.whatISaid);
    }
}
```

This class deserves some explanation.

First, there's a private `ISpecFlowOutputHelper` field called `outputHelper`. Don't worry too much about this, it's just a way of writing my own messages to wherever the test runner shows the test results (I'm using Visual Studio 2019's test explorer, which writes these, along with some output from SpecFlow, to the test detail summary for each test case).

Then there are two more private instance fields called `animal` and `whatISaid`. These are for sharing information between different methods in the `AnimalSteps` class, and because they're instance fields, they're specific to the current instance of the `AnimalSteps` class, i.e. each time a new `AnimalSteps` object is created, it has its own values for those fields, completely independent of the values of those fields in any other `AnimalSteps` objects. And because they're private, they're accessible only from within the `AnimalSteps` class, so they can't really be called global.

And there's a private static field called `someStaticField`. This is also only accessible from within the `AnimalSteps` class, but because it's static (the opposite of instance), its value is shared between all instances of the `AnimalSteps` class. This is also why references to this field aren't prefixed with `this.` when references to the other fields are - this field isn't a member of `this` instance of `AnimalSteps`, it's a member of ALL instances of `AnimalSteps`.

So let's look at the output (this is what it looks like in the VS test explorer, it may look different depending on the test runner you're using):

```
    Given I am a "cat"
    -> In constructor: someStaticField is now 1
    -> In constructor: SomeStaticClass.Counter is now 1
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Given_IAmA("cat") (0.0s)
    When I speak
    -> Storing what the animal said. Previous value: ''
    -> done: AnimalSteps.When_ISpeak() (0.0s)
    Then I say "meow"
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Then_ISay("meow") (0.0s)
```

```
    Given I am a "cow"
    -> In constructor: someStaticField is now 3
    -> In constructor: SomeStaticClass.Counter is now 3
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Given_IAmA("cow") (0.0s)
    When I speak
    -> Storing what the animal said. Previous value: ''
    -> done: AnimalSteps.When_ISpeak() (0.0s)
    Then I say "moo"
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Then_ISay("moo") (0.0s)
```

```
    Given I am a "dog"
    -> In constructor: someStaticField is now 2
    -> In constructor: SomeStaticClass.Counter is now 2
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Given_IAmA("dog") (0.0s)
    When I speak
    -> Storing what the animal said. Previous value: ''
    -> done: AnimalSteps.When_ISpeak() (0.0s)
    Then I say "woof"
    -> done: AnimalSteps.Then_ISay("woof") (0.0s)
```

A couple of things to note from this:

- The value of the `whatISaid` field is an empty string in each test case, until it's set in that test case. This is because it's an instance field, and each test case is using a new instance of `AnimalSteps`.
- The value of the `someStaticField` field is different each time. This is because it's shared between all instances of `AnimalSteps`, and the `AnimalSteps` constructor is adding 1 to it each time a new instance is created.
- We can see from the values of `someStaticField` that the test cases are being run in the order cat, dog, cow. This is neither the same as the order in which they appear in the feature file (dog, cat, cow), nor the order in which they appear in the VS test explorer (cat, cow, dog).

That last point is important, because what SpecFlow does is generate unit tests for your code, and unit tests should be independent of each other; you can't make any assumptions about the order that they'll run in, and one test shouldn't be dependent on another test having already run.

I haven't mentioned `SomeStaticClass` yet. This is what it looks like:

```
public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

This is a bit like the static `someStaticField` field, except that it's not private to the `AnimalSteps` class, you can access it and its members from anywhere in your application, without needing to create an instance of it and then having to keep track of what that instance is. If you really want globally declared variables, then static classes are probably the best way to do it.

I hope this digression from your question is helpful in understanding scope and what is accessible from where in your application and its tests. But the main point is that trying to pass values from one unit test to another isn't really a good idea, because you can't be sure what order they'll be run in. If your test case needs to check the outcome of a particular action, then it's probably best to include that action in your test scenario, for example:

```
Given I have navigated to the UserDetails page
Given I enter <UserID>, <Name>, 
Given I click on Create button
When I have navigated to the StudentCourse page
Then the user ID and name on that page will be <UserID>, <Name>
```